# php mail on gmail - am I crazy or what?

Tags: php, email, gmail, email-headers

This is my php function :

```
$message="Hello";
$headers='From: "Sender" <sender@hosting.com>'."\r\n".'Reply-To: sender@hosting.com'."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
mail("destination@gmail.com", "Title", $message, $headers);
```

I get the mail on gmail, but when I click on Reply I see in the fields :

```
From : sender@hosting.com
To : destination@gmail.com
```

:O It should be the opposite. Why this trouble?

**EDIT**

This is the header of the gmail's mail when I get it :

```
from    My Hosting sender@hosting.com trougth webxc13s09.ad.aruba.it 
reply to    sender@hosting.com
to  destination@gmail.com
```

and That's correct! When I open that mail and I click on Reply, the Gmail Fields From/To are populated as :

```
from : sender@hosting.com
to : destination@gmail.com
```

but is wrong. Should be

```
from : destination@gmail.com
to : sender@hosting.com
```

Comment: Try using `\n` only. Also, it's usually better to avoid `X-Mailer` - many spam filters react to it... Anyway, which "fields" do you mean exactly? GMail's? I'd be really surprised if that were the case. Do you mean the quoted message?

Comment: No! When i open the message and I do "reply", the from field is with the destinator mail, and the to field is with the mail of "to" of the header. Looks like they are swapped...

Comment: that's really weird. I don't know what could cause that

Answer (score 0):

Just tested that myself. Why do you think that's incorrect?

From PHP doc:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

**EDIT**

Well after reading your Edit I pressed the reply button in Gmail.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyOU3.png) still looks OK to me. Sorry that I couldn't help.

Comment: He is getting the wrong order when *replying* to the E-Mail on the recipient's end.